# Can perfect information storage exist?

Tags: quantum-information, information

It's commonly known that [even our best methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_degradation) for storing information eventually [decay naturally](http://www.iasa-web.org/decay-polymers-information-storage-carriers/summary-paper) or are altered (even slightly) every time they are accessed. This even shows itself [in the quantum scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_cryptography) where simply observing a "particle" changes its state. It's also a common problem for naturally-occurring storage devices [like the human brain](http://www.northwestern.edu/newscenter/stories/2012/09/your-memory-is-like-the-telephone-game.html).

So my question is this: Is it even possible to create a "perfect" information storage medium, electrical/chemical/quantum/anything, such that it will not decay or be altered when read?

Answer (score 2):

Trivially, yes. Macroscopic etched diamond kept close to absolute zero will not deteriorate for billions of years.

More to the point, we have [etched Tungsten](http://newatlas.com/billion-year-data-storage/29530/)

> A researcher at the University of Twente in the Netherlands has
>   developed a new optical memory device out of tungsten and silicon
>   nitride that he says could store data safely for extremely long
>   periods of time – up to a billion years.
>
> Hard drives are very susceptible to external magnetic fields and
>   mechanical failures, with a normal lifespan not much longer than 10
>   years; similarly CDs, DVDs and flash drives each have their own
>   Achilles' heel.
>
> University of Twente researcher Jeroen de Vries set out to solve this
>   problem by designing his own data storing device. For the materials he
>   chose tungsten, which can withstand very high temperatures,
>   encapsulated in silicon nitride, which is highly resistant to fracture
>   and deforms very little when exposed to high levels of heat.

Comment: What about the likelihood of  failure of the cooling equipment? And the chance that a fire breaks out and burns the diamond? What about the natural oxidation rate of diamond in air?

Comment: @freecharly Store it in interstellar space, in an asteroid, in vacuum

Comment: It is suspected (but not proved) that protons decay with a half-life of 10^31 -- 10^36 years.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay